# Meaning of a big O in an exponent

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity, exponential, exponent

What does this expression *f*(*n*) = 2<sup>*O*(*n*)</sup> mean, in an exact formal manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `f(n) = 2^O(n)` is equivalent to

```
log_2(f(n)) = O(n)
```

(actually, any logarithm will do), so it means that there is some constant `C > 0` such that

```
log_2(f(n)) <= C*n  <=> f(n) <= 2^(C*n)
```

for all large enough `n`. Now, a<sup>b*c</sup> = (a<sup>b</sup>)<sup>c</sup>, so another way to put it is to say

```
f(n) = O(b^n)
```

for some `b > 0`. This `b` could be `1.5`, or `4`, or `1000000000000`, so it doesn't tell you too much. All it gives you is that `f` is exponential, so it's asymptotically better than `O(n!)`, but it doesn't tell you whether it's pretty bad, bad, really bad or truly catastrophically bad.

Comment: Therefore, examples of f(n) = 2^O(n) include: f(n) = 2^n; f(n) = 2^(3n) = 8^n; f(n) = 2^(100)n = bigBase^n, etc. In other words, f(n) = anyBase^n.